# Parsing Laravel response to proper JSON

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js

I am using Vue with Laravel 5.6 and I am trying to create a list element.
My template is below, the problem is that I cannot properly use the response. For this example I have one item returning but in real examples there will be batches of 10 items. Need a way to transform the gibberish into readable normal JSON

```
<template>
        <div>
            <tr v-for="row in list" v-bind:key='row.id'>
                <td align="left">{{row.list_type_id}}</td>

            </tr>
        </div>
    </template>

        <script>

        export default {
            name: 'List',
            data(){
                return{
                    list:{
                    }
                }
            },
            created() {
                this.getList()
            },
            methods:{
                getList(){
                    let self = this
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/api/list',
                        success: function(result){
                            self.list = result;
                    }});
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
```

This is the response I get from Laravel;

```
[{"data":"{\"list_name\":\"STLTV2\",\"device_type_id\":\"6758\",\"entity_id\":\"1072\",\"client_id\":\"msx\"}]
```

Well normally other then data there are different keys but to be able to prase this I am neglecting them for now.

Ah, also in my model I have

```
protected $casts = [
    'data' => 'json'
];
```

Adding my controller where I only return data

```
public function index()
{
    return \DB::table('list_items')
        ->join('list', 'list_items.list_id', '=', 'list.id')
        ->where('list.type',3)
        ->limit(1)
        ->select(['data'])
        ->get();

}
```

As I limit the returned record with `limit(10` and only select `data` column I can use 
`self.list = JSON.parse(result[0]['data']);` I want to be able to convert `data` as well as other fields

```
{
 'list_id': 1,
 'data': {
     'list_name':'STLTV2',
     ...
  }
}
```

Adding ListItem Model

```
class ListItem extends Model
{

    protected $casts = [
        'data' => 'json'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'list_id',
        'data',
    ];

    public function list()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Lists::class, 'list_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Adding Lists Model

```
class Lists extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'view' => 'json',
        'settings' => 'json'
    ];

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ListItem::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you outputting your json content? E.g show some code on what kind of response you are returning.

Comment: you should put self.list instead of self.form, you don't form variable inside your component data. therefore can you share with us your controller, please?

Comment: Added my controller as well.

Comment: @JerryLi as I expected you should restructuring your return data from the controller, before that can you share with us the relationship between list and list_items table, please?

Comment: You should use [Eloquent resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources) to output well-formed JSON responses.

Comment: Thank you @Thamerbelfkih! You mean this by relation?list_items.list_id', '=', 'list.id'

Comment: @JerryLi yes the relationship between list and list_items Models, please

Comment: @JerryLi can you share with me all the fields that you want to return, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want you should update your `index` method like below:

here we will use `Eloquent` to select our data

```
public function index()
    {
        // here we get all listItems with list that has type = 3  
        $listItems = ListItem::with('lists' => function($query) {
            $query->where('type',3);
        })->get();

        return $listItems->map(function($item){

            return [
                'list_id' => $item->list_id,
                'list_item_id' => $item->list_item_id,

                 // put here all your data like key => value, and then you can get them from your vue component
                //'key' => value
            ];
        });
    }
```

Comment: ```$listItems = ListItem::with(['list' => function($query) {
            $query->where('type',3);
        }])->get();``` needs [] but when I use `toSql()` I only get `select * from list_item` and thats it. There is no connection in the migrations on these two tables, do you think thats the reason?

Comment: @JerryLi you don't have the list_id foreign key within list_items table, please?

Comment: ```$listItems =LisItem::whereHas('lists', function($q) {
            $q->where('type', '3');
        })->get();
        return $listItems;``` this sorted my issue. Thank you for the heads up @Thamer

Answer (score 0):

A better approach may be to use API Resoruces to work with the response of the api.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#generating-resources

In your index function

```
public function index()
{
    return return YourResource::collection(YourModel::all());

}
```